# jQuery doesn't want add class without point

Tags: html, jquery, class

jQuery doesn't want add class without point.

Here's the html markup:

```
<div class="form-group" id="plis">
    <select class="form-control-input notEmpty" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>Choisissez</option>
      <option value="1">1 km</option>
      <option value="2">2 km</option>
      <option value="3">5 km</option>
      <option value="3">10 km</option>
      <option value="3">20km</option>
    </select>
    <label class="label-control" for="spassword">Carburant</label>
    <div class="help-block with-errors" id="distance"></div>
</div>
```

I want to transform this :

```
<div class="form-group" id="plis">...
```

To this :

```
<div class="form-group has-error has-danger" id="plis">...
```

First attempt with this jQuery code:

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Choisissez') {
        $('div#plis').addClass('.has-error has-danger');
        $("div#distance").append("<ul class='list-unstyled' style='margin-top: 0.375rem;'><li>Its works</li></ul>");
    }
});
```

The result :

```
<div class="form-group .has-error" id="plis">...
```

Where is the "has-danger" ?

---

Second attempt:

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Choisissez') {
        $('div#plis').addClass('has-error has-danger');
        $("div#distance").append("<ul class='list-unstyled' style='margin-top: 0.375rem;'><li>Its works</li></ul>");
    }
});
```

The result :

```
<div class="form-group" id="plis">...
```

Why did nothing happen ?

---

Third attempt:

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Choisissez') {
        $('div#plis').addClass('has-error .has-danger');
        $("div#distance").append("<ul class='list-unstyled' style='margin-top: 0.375rem;'><li>Its works</li></ul>");
    }
});
```

The result :

```
<div class="form-group .has-danger" id="plis">...
```

Where is the "has-error" ?

---

Fourth attempt:

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Choisissez') {
        $('div#plis').addClass('.has-error .has-danger');
        $("div#distance").append("<ul class='list-unstyled' style='margin-top: 0.375rem;'><li>Its works</li></ul>");
    }
});
```

The result :

```
<div class="form-group .has-error .has-danger" id="plis">...
```

Why doesn't jQuery add the class without a point?

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't add the dot, just the names of the classes `addClass('has-error has-danger')`

Comment: The dot is a "class selector" - you don't want a selector, you want just the class names.  https://api.jquery.com/addclass/  *One or more space-separated classes* - it's unclear. from the code provided, why your attempts with out the dot didn't work.

Comment: In the second attempt, neither classes were added. I'm assuming some logic in the conditional was at fault here

Comment: I did that ```$('div#plis').addClass('has-error has-danger');```
but the result is : ```<div class="form-group" id="plis"> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation of [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), you only add the class names you want to add, separated by a space. You don't need to specify the "dot" as it's a class selector.

```
$('div#plis').addClass('has-error has-danger');
```

I know you tried your second example and you say it didn't work but as you can see by the snippet below, it does indeed work. I added the red color to only elements that have the classes `has-error` and `has-danger`.

Bare in mind, this only works if you select an option, then select `Choisissez` again. This is because the event listener you've created is only fired on `change`.

```js
$( "select" ).change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Choisissez') {
            $('div#plis').addClass('has-error has-danger');
            $("div#distance").append("<ul class='list-unstyled' style='margin-top: 0.375rem;'><li>Its works</li></ul>");
        }
    })
```

```css
.has-error.has-danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="plis">
    <select class="form-control-input notEmpty" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>Choisissez</option>
      <option value="1">1 km</option>
      <option value="2">2 km</option>
      <option value="3">5 km</option>
      <option value="3">10 km</option>
      <option value="3">20km</option>
    </select>
    <label class="label-control" for="spassword">Carburant</label>
    <div class="help-block with-errors" id="distance"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation, but why it doesn't work for me ? :(

Comment: As you can see in my question in the 2nd try, I did that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you that it does work.

Answer (score 0):

it works if you just make that `addClass('has-error has-danger')` (i.e. no dots, classes seperated by space):

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Choisissez') {
    $('div#plis').addClass('has-error has-danger');
    $("div#distance").append("<ul class='list-unstyled' style='margin-top: 0.375rem;'><li>It works</li></ul>");
  }
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.has-danger {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="plis">
  <select class="form-control-input notEmpty" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>Choisissez</option>
    <option value="1">1 km</option>
    <option value="2">2 km</option>
    <option value="3">5 km</option>
    <option value="3">10 km</option>
    <option value="3">20km</option>
  </select>
  <label class="label-control" for="spassword">Carburant</label>
  <div class="help-block with-errors" id="distance"></div>
</div>
```